# C# HtmlDecode from XElement (string) is not working

Tags: c#, htmldecode, httputility

I working with a xml file.
I get a string from it, and this string is encoding in html;
I try to use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode but, it's not working...
What am I missing?
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4amRW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

`nbsp;` is an **invalid** HTMLEncoded entity, `&nbsp;` is a valid 1 representing Non-Breaking Space.

Example

```
var aStr = @"<root> <children> <child1> This is &nbsp; &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt; &nbsp;&nbsp; </child1> <child2> This is nbsp; &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt; nbsp;nbsp; </child2></children> </root>";
var decoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(aStr);
// decoded value "<root> <children> <child1> This is   <b>bold</b>    </child1> <child2> This is nbsp; <b>bold</b> nbsp;nbsp; </child2></children> </root>"
```